# Algorithm for navigating a matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, arduino-uno

So I have a robot and it has five infrared sensors(leftmost,left-middle,middle,right-middle,rightmost), and  I have a 5*5 square matrix that I want my robot to navigate.

The actions my robot can take are:
-Forward(following the line using 3 inner sensors i.e. left-middle, middle, right-middle)
-turnleft
-turnright
-turnaround

I know the initial position of the robot in the grid and it's orientation(the direction it's facing i.e. North, south, east,west).

Now I want to come up with an algorithm such that when the initial position of my robot is (0,0) and orientation is North and then when I give my Robot co-ordinates like (2,1), It should first turnRight, then move two columns to the left and then turnleft and move one column up to reach the co-ordinate (2,1).

Is there an algorithm out there that does this? I came up with an algorithm myself but it is quite lengthy(200+ loc), So I am looking for an efficient algorithm.

P.s.- The robot have no idea where the co-ordinates are in the grid, it only has it's sensors to detect the row and columns and there cross-sections and make decisons based on that. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Let me sumarize:

Your robot can go only in four directions (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT).

```
M = 
+---------+
|        E|
|         |
|         |
|         |
|    S    |
+---------+

Robot start position is S(0,2)
End position is E(4,4)
```

There are few paths with the same length from S to E.

```
+---------+ +---------+ +---------+ +---------+ 
|        E| |        E| |        E| |        E| 
|        +| |        +| |        +| |      + +| 
|        +| |        +| |      + +| |      +  | 
|        +| |      + +| |      +  | |      +  | 
|    S + +| |    S +  | |    S +  | |    S +  | 
+---------+ +---------+ +---------+ +---------+ . . .
```

The point is that all paths are 5(+1) steps long. So you can easily calculate those:

```
S = M[0][2]     (M[i][j], Si = 0, Sj = 2)
E = M[4][4]     (M[i][j], Ei = 4, Ej = 4) 

up_or_down = Ei-Si = 4-0 = 4  // sign is positive (so UP)
if (up_or_down > 0) then UP
                    else DOWN

left_or_right = Ej-Sj = 4-2 = 2  // sign is positive (so RIGHT)
if (left_or_right > 0 then RIGHT
                      else LEFT
```

Final path, that your robot should go is:

```
4xUP
2XRIGHT
```

Any combination of UP and RIGHT will work.

#### Optimisation if robot can go diagonally

In our case it would be:

```
+---------+
|        E|
|        x|
|        x|
|      x  |
|    S    |
+---------+
```

In total it is 3(+1) steps.

With the previous formula we got 4 UPs, and 2 RIGHTs. So we have:

```
path = 4*U + 2*R
path = U+U+U+U+R+R

// let's combine U and R as much as possible
path = U + R + U + R + U + U
       \   /   \   /                // combine U+R into DUR (diagonal-up-right)
path =  DUR  +  DUR + U + U         // it gives us 3(+1) step
```

Comment: from what you said I will have to callibrate it for every move I make meaning the robot will have to move through the grid for every single move but that seems even longer of a process

Comment: If we define MOVE as a path from START to END, then answer is yes. Single move has multiple STEPS and there is no need to compute it again for every STEP. BFS and DFS algorithms are quite fast but there is also space for improvement. I will update the answer with this optimization. What is your approach? Lines of code usually tells nothing about performance...

Comment: I got your point, it is not the graph problem. Just a simple play with matrix indices, please ignore the answer, I will write the new one